# Chrome position:fixed inside position:absolute breaking with iframe / video

Tags: css

I've spent 2 hours on this crazy bug on one of my websites which has huge amount of content, until I figured what was causing the issue; On Chrome it appears that **position:fixed** element inside a **position:absolute** element (which has a z-index) would not work like a **position:fixed** element would.

---

Note - **only** on *Chrome windows* (not on ubuntu).

---

I want to post this question and my answer so others won't get frustrated from Chrome and it's crazy bugs. see demo:

**TEST PAGE: http://jsbin.com/uhuzoy/2/edit**

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**FIX**: add these rules to the `position:fixed` element:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

Comment: This fix is unfortunately not universal. In my case, it does not fix the issue.

Comment: I think Google had changed something and this might not work anymore on some situations. I had a problem today which this did not solve and I was very surprised because this fix worked 100% of the time till now whenever a flicker abnormality was happening.

Comment: **NOTE** - If the absolute parent has a translate, the fixed element will be based on the parents coordinates, not the viewport.