# Absolute positioned HTML5 video element with negative z-index breaks background-attachment in webkit browsers

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, webkit, html5-video

I'm using an HTML5 video element as a background layer which works fine, however, it's causing problems with other elements on the page that have a background image with the property `background-attachment: fixed`. The background images become unstuck, broken up, or disappear completely. If I change the z-index of the video wrapper div to something positive the problem disappears but that defeats the purpose of using it as a background layer. This problem is only occurring in webkit browsers (Chrome and Safari).

Here's the basic HTML:

```
<section class="fixed-background">
    <p>...</p>
</section>

<section>
    <div class="video-background">
        <video loop autoplay muted>
            <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
        </video>
    </div>
    <p>...</p>
</section>

<section class="fixed-background">
    <p>...</p>
</section>
```

And the CSS:

```
.fixed-background {
    background: url('image.jpg') center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
.video-background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1;
}
.video-background video {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

I've created a sample [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CP9uQ/) that illustrates the problem. Works fine in Firefox, but breaks in Chrome/Safari.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? Was it Corey's?

Comment: @LeeProbert None of the answers provided fixed the issue for my particular case. The problem is no longer present in current versions of Safari, however, Chrome (44.0.2403) still has issues painting the fixed background.

Answer (score 18):

Did you find a fix for this?
I have the same issue, however only in safari.

**Edit**
This post here fixed it for me.

[Chrome position:fixed inside position:absolute breaking with iframe / video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17068361/chrome-positionfixed-inside-positionabsolute-breaking-with-iframe-video)

Add this to all position: fixed; elements

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap HTML5 video in dom element with styling rules position: relative; and overflow:hidden; This will fix everything in all browsers!

Answer (score 1):

I ran across the same issue. Corey's fix did not resolve the bug for my `background-attachment: fixed` element.

However, I was able to get it working. Inside the element that declares `background-attachment: fixed` I add `<img style="height: 1px; width: 1px; position: fixed;">`

I'm not entirely sure as to why this works, but I believe it's because the 1x1 pixel forces the browser to repaint the parent element as well.

PS: It doesn't have to be an img element, it can be any element.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kfuchs/631qt93p/)

**Edit:**

This does **NOT** work on Chrome 35 Ubuntu