# Video tag at Chrome overlays on top

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, video

Other browsers are OK, but only in chrome, video plays on top, ignoring z-index.

Following is code, and it looks strange in Chrome.

There is absolutely positioned 'IUView_4', but it shows under the video.

What's wrong in Chrome? Is there any way to handle?

```
<style>
    #Page {background-color : rgb(255,255,255); position : relative; z-index : 0; width : 100.0%; margin : auto; height : 1300.0px; }
    #Movie {background-color : rgb(0,198,245); top : 94.0px; z-index : 0; width : 521.0px; left : 131.0px; height : 242.0px; }
    #View {height : 70.0px; width : 100.0px; background-color : rgb(0,164,89); z-index : 1; top : 62.0px; overflow : hidden; left : 435.0px; position:absolute;  }
</style>
<body >
    <div>
      <div id='Page' >
          <div id='Movie' >
              <video width=100% height=100% poster='res/gazzetta_thumbnail.png' autoplay>
                  <source src="http://www.sketchin.ch/en/wp-content/themes/Sketchin2013/assets/video/page-home/gazzetta.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                  <object data="http://www.sketchin.ch/en/wp-content/themes/Sketchin2013/assets/video/page-home/gazzetta.mp4" width="100%" height="100%" /> </object>
              </video>
          </div>
          <div id='View' >     
          </div>
       </div>
   </div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We had a similar issue on our site, and implemented the [fix described in this stack overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17068361/chrome-positionfixed-inside-positionabsolute-breaking-with-iframe-video).

In our case, we added the following CSS to a relatively positioned overlay (rather than a fixed position element described in the link above), which kept disappearing behind the video:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you so much

Answer (score 5):

On Google Chrome 64, this did the trick:

```
audio, video { position:relative; z-index:-1; }
```